# How can I print the number of occurences of each value with the value from the csv

Tags: python, list, csv

I am working on a cdr visualization and I need to get the number of each countries. I sorted the countries but I couldnt get the numbers.

```
def country(data):
N = []

for i in data:
      N.append(i.getcallee_country())

counts = [(i, len(list(c))) for i,c in groupby(N)]     
print(counts)
```

Comment: Could you provide sample content of list `N` after execution of `for` loop?

Comment: [ 'ABD'   'Andorra'  'Bae' ...] @Daweo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter looks like a perfect match for the problem

```
import collections

print collections.Counter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b'])
```

Alternatively:

```
c = Counter()
for value in your_list:
    c[value] += 1
```

Comment: This is what I need.Thank you